# OBJLoader: Unexpected line: "<!doctype html>" three-full not working on Azure works locally

Tags: angular, azure, three.js

I am using 'three-full' package to render 3D images in Angular 7 SPA,  The OBJLoader to load the object is throwing error on Azure while it works absolutely fine locally. Is there something to be done on Azure to ensure it works

-I have already tried to validate my object model but nothing seems wrong
-No network error 
-obj and mtl return with 200 Response

```
   mtlLoader.load(path + name + '.mtl', (materials) => {
     materials.preload();
     var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
     objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
     objLoader.load(path + name + '.obj', (object) => {
       object.name = "__component__" + name;
       object.scale.set(0.005, 0.006, 0.005);
       object.position.x -= 1;
       object.position.z -= 2;
       object.updateMatrix();
       this.scene.add(object);
       this.render();
     });
   });;
```

Also one of the mtl file

```
# CAD Exchanger 3.5.3 (cadexchanger.com)
# Material Count: 1

newmtl Material_1
Ns 0.000000
Ka 0.200000 0.200000 0.200000
Kd 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ks 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ke 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

The error Message I am getting

```
ERROR Error: OBJLoader: Unexpected line: "<!doctype html>"
    at i.parse (5.7bca0b62b1c467d86062.js:1)
    at Object.onLoad (5.7bca0b62b1c467d86062.js:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (5.7bca0b62b1c467d86062.js:1)
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.8bbb231b43165d65d357.js:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.3fb28dbf2ae1d6614882.js:1)
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.8bbb231b43165d65d357.js:1)
    at t.runTask (polyfills.8bbb231b43165d65d357.js:1)
    at t.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.8bbb231b43165d65d357.js:1)
    at m (polyfills.8bbb231b43165d65d357.js:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.k (polyfills.8bbb231b43165d65d357.js:1)
```

**UPDATE - 1 The problem here is my .obj and .mtl files are return as html instead of application/octet-stream OR application/object**

Comment: While not entirely related with your question, `three` package now offers usable ES6 modules for core and examples. So there's no longer the need for using `three-full`. [More info](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Import-via-modules)

Comment: How are you importing `OBJLoader` ?

Comment: I dont know if i understand correctly the loader is inside the three-full node module(as used in the code above) and the reason why i am using three-full is because it exports everything needed. Part of the code from three.js 
` export { OBJLoader } from './loaders/OBJLoader.js'`